# stop the execution in wcf request

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to reply a WCF request in `AfterReceiveRequest` method of message inspector (implements `IDispatchMessageInspector`)

```
  XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(
    new StringReader(string.Format(@"<{0}Response xmlns='{1}' />",methodName,namespace)));

  Message replyMsg = Message.CreateMessage(request.Version, request.Headers.Action, xmlReader);
  OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.Reply(replyMsg);
```

client gets the response immediately by this way.

Rest of the task is to break the execution on server and end up without a fault.

request.Close() breaks the execution, but if you take a look at message in 'BeforeSendReply' ,, it creates a fault.

well its not appropriate for us, and looking for a convenient termination.
is there anyway to do it??

Comment: Can you please try to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish? Why to you want to stop excecution?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely expected behavior.  I don't think you'll be able to get around this.

Using a message inspector for anything but observation or adaptation before passing a message off to a method is probably a bad idea.  It seems like what you are trying to do is more appropriate for the implementation of your operation.  You should see a message inspector as the chance to see a message or tweak it before it's handed off to the dispatcher.

Comment: actually it is the place that authentication, authorization and logging tasks occur, and anything between these tasks and actual action execution should be placed in inspectors 'AfterRequestReceive' method. It works like a single-point-entry implementation.
so if you have an advice about where all these tasks should be done, it will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and eventually found a solution, which I will now share with you.

The thing that you actually want to do is prevent the service operation from being invoked based on some condition you discover in the `AfterReceiveRequest` method. In order to do this, you need to add an `IOperationInvoker` which works in conjunction with your message `IDispatchMessageInspector`

```
class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (SuppressRequest(request, channel, instanceContext))
        {
            request.Properties.Add("SuppressMe", true);
        }
    }

    // Other code omitted
}

class CustomInvoker : IOperationInvoker
{
    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
    {
        // If the message inspector added the "SuppressMe" property, then don't
        // invoke anything and create an empty output.
        if (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.ContainsKey("SuppressMe"))
        {
            bool suppress  = (bool)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["SuppressMe"];
            if (suppress)
            {
                outputs = null;
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Otherwise, go ahead and invoke the operation
        return invoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
    }
}
```

You can then wire up this message inspector and this invoker with your operation using the normal methods (via an attribute or an endpoint behavior specified in the config file).